# Connect create-react-app to django backend without having to run build

Tags: reactjs, django, create-react-app

I connected my react app that I made with create-react-app to django by passing it in as a template. I followed the steps shown here: https://studygyaan.com/django/django-react-setup-best-project-structure.

This works but if I want to try out a full backend server by running manage.py runserver, I have to do npm run build on the frontend app all the time. Is there a way to get it so that I could maybe connect the development components to django instead of the build components? Running the build command always takes a bit of time.

Comment: Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-build-watch